# Запрет на подбор (генерацию) динамческих URL

Tags: html, sql-injection

Здравствуйте. Есть страница типа name.html. Как через .htaccess запретить модифицировать URL через "?" и проставить 301-редирект с таких уязвимых URL, на страницу name.html и подобные?
Сейчас, любым запросом, ссылкой 
[http://name.name/name.html?после_этого_знака_вопрос/](http://name.name/name.html?%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81/) можно получить ответ сервера - 200 (страница существует).

Comment: Почему URL с вопросом уязвимый то. Ладно ещё редиректить для SEO но уязвимость может быть только в коде, который запрос обрабатывает - вот там и делайте редирект, или просто очищаёте список параметров в точке входа, раз так хочется.

Comment: Важно, что эти страницы не существуют, и не должны отдавать ответ 200. Мой вопрос был связан с тем, как такие страницы сделать недоступными.
Что касается уязвимостей.  благодаря такому модификатору, как "?", можно попытаться осуществить слепой подбор.
Меня больше интересует решение первого вопроса.

Comment: `осуществить слепой подбор` какой ещё слепой подбор, что подбирать то будут злоумышленники? Касаемо основного вопроса - так сделайте редирект в коде, так будет лучше, если очень хочется htaccess - то вот ответ на вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457022/mod-rewrite-remove-query-string-from-url

Comment: Имелись ввиду - blind sql-injection. Вроде нашел, спасибо Вам. 
Пример такой:  RewriteRule ^(.*) http://name.name/$1? [R=301,L]
Но у меня некоторые страницы через  ? существуют. Как разрешить определённый список страниц, совместно с этим правилом?

Comment: `sql-injection` инъекции надо обрабатывать не уничтожением параметров, а обработкой параметров в коде контроллеров. Инъекции будут только если ваша `.html` ссылка на самом деле не фига не html - а обрабатывается сервером (php, asp, java), при чём дырявым. То есть за инъекциями по-другому следят, иначе дыры у вас никуда не денутся. 99% инъекций уходит при пользовании построителем запросов, например https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/ru/zend.db.select.html (для PHP)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ по уязвимостям, но мой основной вопрос был: "Как разрешить определённый список страниц, совместно с этим правилом?"

Comment: я не знаю, для меня синтаксис правил .htaccess всегда казался китайским - его только бородатые админы понимают) Знаю только, что обычно подобные редиректы делают в коде, а .htaccess копируют стандартный - который все запросы ведёт на index